# Removing Worksheets via Worksheets.Remove()

Tags: vba, collections

I am attempting to remove Worksheets via VBA code. The general idea here is that when the number of worksheets reaches 18, we delete the end worksheet. Now as worksheets are a collection, I have attempted:

```
   If Worksheets.Count = 18 Then
   Worksheets.Remove (Worksheets.Count)
   End If
```

But get an error. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable alerts first, and then use the delete method.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Thank you. Why is this the case?

Comment: First, the proper method is `Delete`, not `Remove`.  Second, the deletion usually requires user confirmation, so you need to disable the alerts to bypass it, and re-enable them so you don't miss any important ones.

Comment: should you care about avoiding unnecessary calculations use `Worksheets(18).Delete`, since you get there right after `Worksheets.Count` has already been evaluated as such a value

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Worksheets.Delete("SheetName")` instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837404.aspx.

```
If Worksheets.Count = 18 Then
   Worksheets.Delete(Worksheets.Count)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub WorksheetDelete()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False    'To avoid display alert
Do Until ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count>=18
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(18).Delete 'Delete the 18th worksheet 
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True     'Turn on the Alerts

End Sub
```